# Change installation directory of XQuartz on Mountain Lion

Tags: x11, xquartz

Mountain Lion doesn't include X11 any more, and XQuartz is the substitute.  Having installed it, I see that XQuartz 2.7.2 installs in the non-standard (though commonly used) directory /opt.  It also installs symlinks from /usr/X11 to /opt/X11.

I would prefer having XQuartz only use /usr/X11 and not create /opt/X11.

Is there a way to change the installation directory of XQuartz on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Any changes for /usr/X11 with XQuartz 2.7.5 and Mavericks?

Answer (score 1):

Get the sources and compile it yourself, setting the paths you prefer.